# Verifying matrix transpose function in FRAMA-C

Tags: frama-c

I have a simple matrix transpose function which I would like to verify with a postcondition such that

```
matrix_transpose(matrix_transpose(original_matrix)==original_matrix
```

What would be the syntax for that? I've tried

```
ensures \result(\result)==a;
```

where a is the original matrix, but that doesn't seem to work.

Edit: This is my code

```
    void transpose_matrix(int[][10],int,int);
int main()
{       
        int r=3;
        int c=3;
        int a[10][10]={
                {1,1,1},
                {2,2,2},
                {3,3,3}
               };

        transpose_matrix(a,r,c);


    return 0;
}
/*@
ensures \result(\result)==a;
*/

void transpose_matrix(int a[][10], int r, int c){
        int  trans[10][10],i,j;
        for(i=0; i<r; ++i)
                for(j=0; j<c; ++j)
                {       
                        trans[j][i]=a[i][j];
                }

}
```

Perhaps I am not thinking about this in the right way.

Comment: I'm afraid some more details would be necessary. Your specification seems too high-level, and there is no way for the tools to "guess" everything at once. Does your function contain loops? Does it assign global variables? Without the code it's impossible to know what's the problem. Consider providing something like a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, an iterative approach is the only way to understand what's happening. Also, which plug-in are you using? WP? Note that WP is modular, so chaining calls requires some work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the WP plugin. I am more familiar with the likes of Coq and F* where you can ask the theorem prover to check simple mathematical properties of your code in a relatively straightforward manner, so it's definitely possible that my whole approach is just off here!

Comment: In Coq you have a tactics language which allows you to guide the theorem prover. In Frama-C/WP you have some similar situations, e.g. with loops and *loop invariants*, and also an *interactive proof terminator*, in the graphical interface, which is however less advanced than Coq's ProofGeneral or Coq's IDE. But I believe your main issue is related to Virgile's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The property you want to prove cannot really be expressed with a simple function contract as offered by ACSL. Namely a function contract specifies what should happen during a single function call. What you're after to concerns *two* related function calls.

There is an external (and very experimental) plug-in of Frama-C that let you write this kind of properties: RPP (Relational Properties Prover), available at https://github.com/lyonel2017/Frama-C-RPP, with some articles describing the technique (known as *self-composition*) on which it is based at https://hal-cea.archives-ouvertes.fr/cea-01808885 and https://hal-cea.archives-ouvertes.fr/cea-01835470

Note that in its current state, RPP has many limitations, notably with respect to handling pointers, which will probably be a problem for matrices. It might be however possible to do self-composition manually and then use WP as usual.